# How to exclude all files except one in gitlab-ci artifacts with

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a folder structure like

```
foo/bar/lorem/a.txt
foo/bar/lorem/b.txt
foo/bar/lorem/c.ext
foo/bar/ipsum/p.txt
foo/bar/ipsum/q.ext
```

In GitLab CI's yml `artifacts` I want to include everything in `foo/bar`, `exclude *.txt` but include `b.txt`

The [GitLab CI reference for artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#artifacts) says that:

> Wildcards can be used that follow the [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) patterns and golang's [filepath.Match](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Match).

Try 1:

```
job1:
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - foo/bar/
      - foo/bar/lorem/b.txt
    exclude:
      - foo/bar/**/*.txt
```

Try 2:

```
job1:
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - foo/bar/
    exclude:
      - foo/bar/**/!(b).txt
```

Expected output:

```
foo/bar/lorem/b.txt
foo/bar/lorem/c.ext
foo/bar/ipsum/q.ext
```

What `paths` and `exclude` combination do I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
job1:
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - foo/bar/lorem/b.txt
      - foo/bar/*/*.ext
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the previous answer is good and correct, it relies on a particular case where there are only two types of files. Having a whole hierarchy with multiple file types, that could possibly be different for each job, makes it very hard to apply to other cases.

Here is an answer, a bit more difficult to set up, but that covers more cases, if someone else is looking for an answer:

---

At the end of your `script` section, delete the files you don't want. For example:

```yaml
job1:
  script:
    - # Perform the actions you already do
    - mkdir keep # Create a place to temporarly keep your files
    - mv foo/bar/lorem/b.txt keep/ # Move the file to the safe place
    - rm foo/bar/*.txt # Delete all files you want to delete
    - mv keep/b.txt foo/bar/lorem/ # Put back the file you want to keep
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - foo/bar/ # Save everything, the *.txt are already removed
```

*Note for the anxious:* CI jobs are run in a container (at least it's the default behavious), and the files you work on are a copy of your project. You can delete whatever you want, nothing will be lost outside the container.